# How do I execute a command with quotation marks in an argument?

Tags: shell, rust, command-line-arguments, execute

I'm trying to run the command

```
rsync -rtv -e 'ssh -i /Users/yuanlinfeng/.ssh/id_rsa -o "UserKnownHostsFile=/dev/null" -o "StrictHostKeyChecking no" -o "ConnectTimeout=2"' /tmp/a username@ip:/home/ubuntu/a
```

The code is:

```
let login_settings = format!(r#"'ssh -i {} -o "UserKnownHostsFile=/dev/null" -o "StrictHostKeyChecking no" -o "ConnectTimeout=2"'"#, identity);
let mut cmd = Command::new("rsync");
cmd.env("SETTING", login_settings);
cmd.arg("-rtv").arg("-e").arg(login_settings);
if delete {
    cmd.arg("--delete");
}
match exclude_files {
    None => {}
    Some(exclude_files) => {
        for file in exclude_files.iter() {
            cmd.arg("--exclude").arg(file);
        }
    }
}
let target = format!("{}@{}:{}", username, remote_ip, dest);
cmd.arg(source).arg(target);
let output = cmd.output()?;
if output.stdout.len() > 0 {
    println!("stdout: {}", String::from_utf8_lossy(&output.stdout));
}
if output.stderr.len() > 0 {
    println!("stderr: {}", String::from_utf8_lossy(&output.stderr));
}
```

The error:

```
stderr: rsync: Failed to exec ssh -i /Users/yuanlinfeng/.ssh/id_rsa -o "UserKnownHostsFile=/dev/null" -o "StrictHostKeyChecking no" -o "ConnectTimeout=2": No such file or directory (2)
rsync error: error in IPC code (code 14) at /BuildRoot/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/rsync/rsync-52/rsync/pipe.c(86) [sender=2.6.9]
rsync: connection unexpectedly closed (0 bytes received so far) [sender]
rsync error: error in rsync protocol data stream (code 12) at /BuildRoot/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/rsync/rsync-52/rsync/io.c(453) [sender=2.6.9]
```

It looks like the quotation marks in the arguments are removed. How do I fix it?

I'm using macOS High Sierra and Rust 1.22.1.

Comment: If you look at the error output it complains about not being able to exec your command, due to a file not being found. Can you verify that it exists?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `'` quotes around the `ssh ...` argument are not actually passed to `rsync`; they are used by the shell to separate the arguments to `rsync`.

Your Rust code tries to call something like this: `rsync -e "'ssh ...'" ...`. rsync then tries to split the `'ssh ...'` argument similar to the shell (it seems it doesn't actually use the shell to expand it). This means it will see `ssh ...` as one argument (the filename to execute) but such a file doesn't exist.

Remove the `'` quotes in your `format!` call, and it might work.

On Linux you could run your example through `strace -ff -e trace=execve -- ./target/...` to see how this works.  macOS has `dtruss`, but I can't help you with that :)